# Почему this здесь ссылается на класс?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Вот пример кода

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: this.props.counter
    }
  
  
  incCounter = () => {
    if (this.state.counter < 50) {
      this.setState(state => ({
        counter: state.counter + 1
      }))
    }
  }
```

Почему здесь `this` ссылается на `App` или тут

```
resetCounter = () => {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.props.counter
    })
  }
```

Как работает это правило? Эти функции находятся не внутри `App` но всё равно ссылаются на него.

Comment: Почему они не внутри `App`? Они внутри же.

Comment: Значит весь код внутри App?

Comment: @CrazyElf   это так?

Comment: Я `JavaScript` не очень знаю, но судя по всему так. Это же всё внутри описания класса `App` происходит.

Comment: Вот статеечка на тему `this` в JS... https://doka.guide/js/function-context/

Comment: потому что стрелочная функция)

Comment: На класс или на экземпляр класса? Это разные вещи

Comment: Кроме того, функция `incCounter` находится очень даже внутри класса `App`

Comment: Всем спасибо,пусть вас хранит бог,я ошибался только из-за того что не знал что весь код находится внутри App поэтому и не понимал в чём проблема

Comment: Более того, в этом примере `incCounter` вообще внутри конструктора находится…